# Upload Files to Google Drive Using PHP API

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm currently trying to upload a test file to google drive using the php api. I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
 }
}
```

Here is how I am creating the client:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Drive API PHP Quickstart');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($this->client);
```

Here is the code that i'm using to upload the file:

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        $file->setName(uniqid().'.jpg');
        $file->setDescription('A test document');
        $file->setMimeType('image/jpeg');

        $data = file_get_contents('test.jpg');

        $createdFile = $this->service->files->create($file, array(
            'data' => $data,
            'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
            'uploadType' => 'multipart'
        ));

        print_r($createdFile);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16978192/google-plus-api-insufficientpermissions-error may give some help.

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your issue, can you provide your whole script without your personal information?

Comment: Did you change at some point the scopes while working on the code? Delete your token file and try again!